# How to select dates within a range in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dml

I created the following table:

```
create table example
(
        code           varchar(7),
        date           date,
CONSTRAINT pk_date PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I inserted the data:

```
insert into example(code, date) 
values('001','2016/05/12');
insert into example(code, date) 
values('002','2016/04/11');
insert into example(code, date) 
values('003','2017/02/03');
```

The question is : how to select the previous dates to five month from today ?

Comment: `mysql,oracle, postgresql`. seriously?

Comment: @1000111 The title says "MySQL" so I deleted the other tags.

Comment: What does * the previous dates to five month from today* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(now(), '%Y%m', date_format(date, '%Y%m')) <= 5
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but I used another similar query through your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` to get all the data having the date in the following range:

```
[Five Months From Today, Today]

SELECT 
*
FROM 
example
WHERE `date` BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND DATE(NOW());
```

Just in case if you are not familiar with `BETWEEN`.

`SELECT 2 BETWEEN 1 AND 3';`

**Result:** `1` (means TRUE)

`SELECT 1 BETWEEN 2 AND 3;`

**Result:** `0` (means FALSE)

**warning:**

Although 2 is between 1 and 3. But the following will return `0`.

`SELECT 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1;`

**Result:** `0` (FALSE)

You should use the lower value before `AND` and the higher value after `AND`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer